# create funciton handle to a complete simulink model for use in matlab e.g. ode45

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to analyse dynamic systems in Matlab. To do so I could e.g. write a derivative function of the system

```
function dydt = vdp1(t,y)
dydt = [y(2); (1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)];
end
```

and the I subject it to a solver-algorithm like:

```
[t,y] = ode45(@vdp1,[0 20],[2; 0]);
```

(taken from https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html )

Unfortunately I have not such an simple system but a huge Simulink model. Conceptually however a Simulink model is also something like a ‘derivative function’

```
dydt = { system derivative given as graphically sketched block diagram }
```

So of course I can run it with `sim` command… as usual.

I want however make some R&D on our big systems targeting questions of steady-state, periodic steady state, stability… .
So I want to have something like a function handle that corresponds to the derivative function of my big Simulink-model:

```
dydt_foo = @<gsbD….>
(gsbD = graphically sketched block diagram)
```

For steady state e.g. I could then find a steady state in state space near `startGuess` with something like

`fsolve(gsbD, startGuess,…)` or find periodic steady state with the help of `bvp4c`.

Up to now I can only play with simple examples but I want to investigate big systems given in form of Simulink-models.
Thus my question is:
I want to have something like a function handle that corresponds to the derivative function represented by a (big) Simulink-model.

Comment: Can you create your own function which calls sim inside that and returns the needed outputs?

Comment: The vast majority of simulink models will not descrive an Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE). How can you be sure yours does?